# VTK do not show output, rendering

Tags: python, rendering, vtk

I wrote this code, but in output, it shows just black screen. Something is missing or I made a mistake somewhere? I use reader, mapper, actor, render and mathemetics.

Changed code with hints from @tomj

Python, VTK 6.2

```
  import vtk



reader = vtk.vtkXMLImageDataReader()
reader.SetFileName("aneurysm.vti")
reader.Update()
data=reader.GetOutput()



math=vtk.vtkImageMathematics()
math.SetInputData(data) 
math.SetConstantC(1024)
math.SetOperationToAddConstant ()
math.Update()

data=math.GetOutput()
reader.Update()
print data.GetScalarRange()

contFilter=vtk.vtkContourFilter()
contFilter.SetValue(1,1250.0)
contFilter.Update()
data=contFilter.GetOutput()

Mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
Mapper.SetInputData(data)


Actor = vtk.vtkActor()
Actor.SetMapper(Mapper)


renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderer.AddActor(Actor)

iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)


iren.Initialize()
renderWindow.Render()
iren.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not using the mapper, your actor has no data to display. You should assign the data to the mapper (Mapper.SetInputData(data), assuming data is of type vtkPolyData) and then the mapper to the actor (Actor.SetMapper(Mapper)).

*Edit after previous was added:* this time it looks like you are missing an input for the contour filter (so contFilter.SetInputData(data) I presume).

Comment: I changed a code with your hints, but its still not working. I've pasted the code in the post.

Comment: It seems that `vtkImageMathematics` has something amiss.  I have a C++ code using it.  It doesn't work, either it yields the input data without any change or noisy values.  I also use `vtkImageFourierFilter` (another image filter) which works just fine.